# Shortcut to go to the next unread mail in Evolution?

Tags: shortcut-keys, evolution, mail

Apparently the period key is the shortcut to go to the next unread mail IF you are in the message list pane. But how do I get there in first place? Isn't there a global shortcut? I do not care which pane has the focus right now, I just want to go to the next unread mail without touching the mouse. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the keyboard shortcut is Ctrl-]